Semicontinuity of set-valued maps
Just recently I started working with set-valued maps and things are quite "confusing" and complicated at the moment. So I would like to ask, maybe a silly question, but would appreciate any help.
Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $f: X \to 2^X$ is a set valued map. We know the following about $f$ is:

It is upper semicontinuous on $X$, which in my case means that for all pair of sequences $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$ such that $y_n \in F(x_n)$ we have $y \in F(x).$ This is also equivalent to say that the graph of $F$ is closed.

$F(x)$ is convex and there exists $M>0$ such that $\|F(x)\| \leqslant M$ for all $x.$

For all $x \in X$, there exists $y \in F(x)$ such that $d(y,\partial F(x)) \geqslant \delta$ for some $\delta > 0.$


I want to prove that these properties imply that $F$ is also lower semicontinuous, which means that for all $y \in F(x)$ and for all sequences $x_n \to x$ we can find a sequence $y_n \in F(x_n)$ such that $y_n \to y.$
This is what I was trying to do:
--- Let $y$ to be fixed, $y \in F(x)$ and $x_n \to x.$ Denote by $y_n^* \in F(x_n)$ the sequence that exists by (3). In particular notice that $y_n^* \in int(F(x_n))$ for each $n$.
--- Moreover, let $\hat x_n, \hat y_n$ be the sequences that exists (by closedness of the graph) such that $\hat x_n \to x$ and $\hat y_n \to y.$
--- Now, for $t \in (0,1)$ define $y_n(t) = ty_n^* + (1-t)\hat y_n$ and notice that for any sequence $t_n \to 0$ we have $y_n(t_n) \to y$. In fact, $$\|y_n(t_n) - y\| = \|t_n(y_n^* - y) + (1-t_n)(\hat y_n - y)\| \to 0$$ due to boundedness of $F(x)$ for all $x$, the convergence $\hat y_n \to y$ and $t_n \to 0.$
--- Now, if I can prove that $y_n(t_n) \in F(x_n)$ for some sequence $t_n$ and for $n$ large, then I am done. But I could not show it at all. I am maybe missing something simple or I am trying to use the wrong idea. The last idea I had was to try to prove that since $x_n \to x$ and $\hat x_n \to x$ and $y \in F(x)$, as $n$ becomes large it will force $\hat y_n$ to be in $F(x_n)$ (since the "end" limit is the same) and then since $y_n^*$ is an interior point and $t_n \in (0,1)$ then $y_n(t_n) \in F(x_n)$.
Does anybody have any idea how to argue this? Or, if my attempt so far is wrong or there is something simpler, I would love to hear about it. As I said: I am a newbie to set-valued functions :).

I do not think that this implies that $F$ is lower semicontinuous, since you could have something like
$$
F(x) := [-1,1] + \begin{cases}
1/x & \text{if } x \ne 0, \\
0 & \text{if } x = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Edit: Next one:
We set $F(0) = [0,\pi]$ and $F(x) = [0,1]$ for all $x \ne 0$.

I should have mentioned that $F(x)$ was uniformly bounded. Sorry, I will edit.

I have given a new counterexample.

You're right. So I need to add more structure to it. Thanks :).

@BGT_MATH You should consider accepting the answer if it takes care of your question.
